# In Skyrim should I go with Imperials or Stormcloaks at the beginning

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I don't know which way to go. Stormcloak Rebellion or Imperial Guards.

Comment: See also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35443/how-does-choosing-imperials-or-stormcloaks-affect-me-later-in-the-game

Comment: @badp Why was this question [re-closed as a duplicate](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/119656/revisions)? It was initially closed as 'Not Constructive' by the community.

Comment: @galacticninja The community notified me that, on second thought, closing as a duplicate was a better idea and I obliged.

Comment: @galacticninja this question is *obviously* a duplicate of the question it is closed against...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It doesn't matter, and very little is changed.

If you go with Ralof, the Stormcloak, you will be able to stay with Gurder in Riverwood.

If you go with Hadvar, the Imperial, you will be able to stay with Alvor, the blacksmith, in Riverwood.

Comment: Which one would you prefer.

Comment: Personally I think going with Hadvir is best, as you can get a couple of free ingots from the blacksmith - handy if you want to level smithing.

Comment: If you like my answer, please mark it as 'accepted' with the tick, and add an upvote with an arrow.

Comment: i would upvote but it says need 15 rep